# HDInsight cluster size when using azure blob storage

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

When using HDInsight and choosing Azure Storage Blob to store the data that needs to be computed, you still have to choose the number of data nodes when provisioning a new cluster.  If your data is being stored on an Azure Storage Blob, what impact does the number of data nodes have?  Is the data from the blob actually replicated onto the data nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put data on the Azure Blob Store, it stays there, and is read directly from Azure Storage.

The data nodes in the HDInsight cluster have two purposes. Firstly, they run the actual compute jobs, which read from Azure Storage Directly. This is not as crazy as it might sound to an HDFS user because of Azure's consistent underlying fabric, which keeps the storage nice and close to the compute.

Secondly, the data nodes are running an HDFS filesystem on their local disk. This is generally only used for intermediate and tmp files in HDInsight, since it is transitory (only lasts as long as the cluster).

So, choosing the number of data nodes is essentially choosing how many job running nodes (yarn application containers, or job tracker slots depending on version) you want to be able to handle, and to a lesser extent, choosing how much temp space your jobs need.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you happen to know any sources for this info?  I'm not finding any for some reAson.

Comment: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-use-blob-storage/ is a good reference for this.